# django tinymce different font size

Tags: python, django, tinymce

In my base template I am using for textarea. It looks like:

```
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
tinymce.init({selector:'textarea',
plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
    "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
    "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
],
});
</script>
```

Here is all good except the font size is small. I dont see any section where I can increase the font size.
How can I fix the font size to be of say 16px. If not then how to change the font size from dropdown..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `content_css`. The CSS file in this setting could be the very CSS file that controls the looks of all your pages. Because then the contents in the editor will also have the looks of your site. Thus the appropriate font-size.

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        content_css : "/mycontent.css"
});
```

That's what a WYSIWYG-editor is all about. ;)